# Separate the records of nsmutablearray according to key

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsmutabledictionary

```
- (NSArray *)graphView:(S7GraphView *)graphView yValuesForPlot:(NSUInteger)myplotIndex {

NSLog(@"Y Axis Records %@ ",detailsArray);

NSMutableArray *yAxisarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

switch (myplotIndex) 
{
    default:
    case 0:


        for (int i=0; i < [detailsArray count]; i++ )

        {
            NSMutableDictionary *tempData=[detailsArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"Systolic details%@",tempData);
            NSMutableString *dataString = [tempData objectForKey:@"systolic"];
            NSLog(@"Systolic %@",dataString);
            [yAxisarray addObject:dataString];

        }
        break;
    case 1:
        for (int i=0; i < [detailsArray count]; i++ )

        {
            NSMutableDictionary *tempData=[detailsArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSMutableString *dataString=[tempData objectForKey:@"diastolic"];
            NSLog(@"Diastolic%@",dataString);
            [yAxisarray addObject:dataString];

        }   
        break;
    case 2:     

        for (int i=0; i < [detailsArray count]; i++ )

        {

            NSMutableDictionary *tempData=[detailsArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSMutableString *dataString=[tempData objectForKey:@"map"];
            NSLog(@"Mean%@",dataString);
            [yAxisarray addObject:dataString];

        }           
        break;
}
return yAxisarray;
}
```

Comment: what does 'accc to key' mean?

Comment: Could not see the switch statement,Post the complete code.

Comment: @Craig White: I've edited the question according to my guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of the processing in a single for loop instead of using a switch case and the iterating 3 times.

```
NSMutableArray *firstArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *secondArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *thirdArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i=0; i < [detailsArray count]; i++ ) {
            NSMutableDictionary *tempData=[detailsArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSMutableString *dataString=[tempData objectForKey:@"firstKey"];
            [firstArray addObject:dataString];

            dataString=[tempData objectForKey:@"secondKey"];
            [secondArray addObject:dataString];

            dataString=[tempData objectForKey:@"thirdKey"];
            [thirdArray addObject:dataString];
}

[yAxisArray addObjectsFromArray:firstArray];
[yAxisArray addObjectsFromArray:secondArray];
[yAxisArray addObjectsFromArray:thirdArray];
```

Comment: I have to add the separate lines in graph.So i have used  switch.But in this code am getting objectforkey errror

Comment: @Sheik: Having to plot separate lines on the graph doesn't mean you need a switch statement. Having three arrays will do the job just as well, faster and more cleanly. As for the `objectForKey:` “error”, you should ask a question about that (or, if *this* is meant to be your question about that, you need to edit your question to make clear what problem you're having and what the exact “error” message is!).